# Display element of IEnumerable<> as header in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a partial view that is using a ViewModel that contains an IEnumerable that I'm loading into a WebGrid. Some of the columns of the WebGrid contain the same data for all rows because this is a filtered view.

I'm trying to display the columns that will always contain identical data across all rows in headers instead. I know I can do this with a ViewBag but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

So if I have a view like this:

```
@model Test.ViewModels.MyModel

@{
    // WebGrid stuff...
    grid.Column("FileName", "File Name"),
    grid.Column("RecordNumber", "Record Number")
}
```

I'm trying to modify like this:

```
@model Test.ViewModels.MyModel

<h1>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.MyModel.FileName)</h1>

@{
    // WebGrid stuff...
    grid.Column("RecordNumber", "Record Number")
}
```

This doesn't work because I can't drill down to the `FileName` column in the IEnumerable via the `HtmlHelper`. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You could use `First` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx or a proper viewmodel.

Comment: @Andreas First worked. If you want to add that as an answer I can mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `First` to get the first item of the enumerable  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx or use a proper viewmodel exposing the header for each line.